# Sails query model always returns undefined

Tags: mongodb, sails.js

I want to get all stream data with thread value but not including `null`. On my mongodb console it works with `$ne` but on my query sails model it always returns `undefined`?

Example query:

```
Stream.findOne({thread: {$ne: null } }, function(err, st){
            if(err) return err;
            console.log("st", st);
       });
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Hi there! I edited your post to try and make it a bit easier to read and follow. Please double check that I've interpreted you correctly and haven't misunderstood what you wanted to say anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Use the **[`.native()`](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/native)** method:

```
Stream.native(function(err, collection) {
    if (err) return res.serverError(err);
    collection.find({
        "thread": { "$ne": null }
    }).toArray(function(err, st) {
        if (err) return res.serverError(err);
        console.log("st", st);
        return res.ok(st);
    });
 });
```

Or the **[`.where()`](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/queries/where)** method:

```
var myQuery = Stream.find();
myQuery.where({'thread':{ '$ne': null}});

myQuery.exec(function callBack(err, results){
    console.log(results)
    });
```

Comment: result is array empty, by the way i'm using adapter sails-mongo @chridam

Comment: can you help me @chridam?

Comment: @monoysuronoy I've added an alternative soultion though I'm not too sure if that should work, worth a try.